# Solving recurrences (tree method) with square roots

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

I am trying to find the upper and lower bounds for this recurrence, but I am not sure how to handle to square root:
$$
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^2\sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: $n^2 \cdot \sqrt{n} = n^{5/4}$, then you proceed as normal. Master Theorem should work here.

Comment: @ryan You meant $n^2\cdot\sqrt{n}=n^{5/2}$, right?

Comment: Oh yes whoops. That is what I meant.

Comment: @ryan Please post answers in the answer box, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2 \cdot \sqrt{n} = n^{5/2}$, then you can proceed with the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) as normal.

If you specifically need to use the [Recursion Tree Method](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture3.pdf) for solving recurrences, then you can still proceed normally.

1. Root Level : $n^{5/2}$
2. Next Level : $4 \cdot (n\ /\ 2)^{5/2} = 2^{4/2} \cdot n^{5/2}\ /\  2^{5/2} = n^{5/2}\ /\ 2^{1/2}$
3. Next Level : $16 \cdot (n\ /\ 4)^{5/2} = 4^{4/2} \cdot n^{5/2}\ /\ 4^{5/2} = n^{5/2}\ /\ 4^{1/2}$
4. etc.